# RequireJS: "return this;" and not have it be global

Tags: javascript, module, namespaces, dependencies, requirejs

I have this code for a module:

```
define(
    [
        "jquery",
    ],
    function
    (
        $
    )
    {
        this.someArray = []
        this.someObject = 
            function(
                        someID
                        somePrivacyType
                    )
                {
                    this.someID         = someID;
                    this.somePrivacyType = somePrivacyType;

                    someArray[this.someID]  = this;
                };

        return this;
    }
);
```

And I want to access the above module using it's namespace from another module, but using `return this;` throws everything in the global namespace. 
 like so:

```
define(
    [
        "jquery",
        "myProject/SomeModule"
    ],
    function
    (
        $,
        SomeModule
    )
    {
        console.log(SomeModule); //Returns window
    //someArray is in the global namespace rather than only
        console.log(someArray); //Returns someArray (Want it to return undefined)
    //on the SomeModule namespace below
        console.log(SomeModule.someArray); //Returns someArray (Want only this to return Array)
        console.log(SomeModule.someObject);

        return this;
    }
);
```

I would like to continue using some type of `return this;` without having to declare the namespace from within the module itself. This way makes it very easy for me to keep private variables by declaring them within the module, but not on `this`. I know I could simply declare the namespace from within the module, but this takes away from the modularity.
Is there any way to pull the namespace of the file from RequireJS or some other way to return `this` as an object which will be referenced only by the namespace it's being called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
    var ns = {}; // Create our namespace.
    ns.someArray = [];
    ns.someObject = function(someID, somePrivacyType) {
        this.someID = someID;
        this.somePrivacyType = somePrivacyType;

        ns.someArray[this.someID]  = this;
    };

    return ns;
});
```

I'm assuming that `ns.someObject` is meant to be called with `new`. I've also assumed that your access to `someArray` in the function assigned to `ns.someObject` is meant to access `someArray` on your namespace, hence `ns.someArray`.

Depending on the nature of your namespace, you might want to use `Object.create(null)` to create it rather than `{}`. `{}` is okay when you have a finite set of keys and you take care not to override the methods defined on `Object`. If not, it is better to use `Object.create(null)` to avoid clashes.

Comment: Awesome works perfectly, and all the assumptions were true... I figured if I did something like namespace.object that I would have to do someModule.namespace.object or explicitly name someModule as the namespace. Turns out that's not true :D... thanks!